# How to copy rows from one table to other in django which meet a particular condition?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to copy all those fields which meet this condition `Table1.objects.filter(post_home=True)` ( where `post_home` is a boolean field in my `Table1`)to my other table `Table2` which have the same fields as `Table1`

Comment: How do you want to handle conflicts? There may already be a row in the other table with the same data

Comment: Oher table(Table2) is initially empty, only those rows where `post_home=True`  is to be copied

Answer (score 2):

run `python manage.py shell`

and do this:

```
from models import Table1, Table2

table1_rows = Table1.objects.filter(post_home=True)

for row in table1_rows.values():
    Table2.objects.create(**row)
```

Comment: You should use `.values()` to return dictionaries so that you can use dictionary unpacking

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to go to shell whenever I want to copy fields?

Comment: you can write your own management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: If you have any `AutoField` fields, won't this screw up postgres's automatic value generation because you're statically setting the value for an `AutoField`?  The next `AutoField` value will step on it and create a unique constraint violation.